# Eclipse : Force UTF-8 in the imported projects

Tags: eclipse, configuration

When I ckeckout a project with CSV/SVN or import it from my local drive, I always have to set its properties to UTF-8 for the "text file encoding" and Unix for the "New text file line delimiter".

Is it possible to configure eclipse so that it applies automatically the UTF8 and Unix settings to the imported projects ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Window - Preferences - General - Workspace

and, for more fine-grained tuning by content type:

Window - Preferences - General - Content types

If you open the Preferences window and type "enco" in the filer text box, Eclipse will show all the preferences panels which contain encoding options.